# about the usage of "the" before a possession construction

Tags: grammar, articles, possessives

There are examples I took from Murphy's English Grammar in Use, Unit 81B

- the Carters' house
- Mr and Mrs Carter's house

I couldn't understand why the latter goes like that and not like "the Mr and Mrs Carter's house"

According to my logic "the" belongs to "house" and not to "Carters"

Comment: It follows the normal rules for use of the possessive. One could say *The friend of Jack*, or *Jack's friend*. If one uses the latter form the article is not used. So it is either *the house of Mr & Mrs Carter* or *Mr & Mrs Carter's house*

Comment: @WS2 I can't get it. Isn't "The friend of Jack" have a more specific meaning than "Jack's friend"? And why then "the Carters' house" is correct?

Comment: Well, in *the Carters' house* the definite article is qualifying *Carters* and not *house*. I don't really see why *the friend of Jack* is considered more specific in meaning than *Jack, his friend* or *Jack's friend*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because "the" doesn't belong to "house" after all.  You're identifying the family as "the Carters" in the first example, and as "Mr. and Mrs. Carter" in the second.

"My house"
"Bob's house"
"Bob Smith's house"
"The Smiths' house"

Comment: Other examples include fictional families such as [The Flintstones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flintstones) and [The Jetsons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jetsons), and the Joneses in the idiomatic expression "[keeping up with the Joneses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keeping_up_with_the_Joneses)". The latter expression inspired the name of the reality TV show *[Keeping Up with the Kardashians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keeping_Up_with_the_Kardashians)*. It is also possible to say "the Kardashian family" or even "the family Kardashian".

Answer (score 1):

In your examples, 'Carter' is a surname.  The definite article is not elided on surnames.  If a given name or title occurs ('Jack' or 'Mister'), then the article is omitted.  (It is redundant since it is expected that you know which 'Carter' is meant.)